# How did walking dead characters get cured?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

I remember in season 4 of *The Walking Dead* that Glenn, Sasha and a few others were infected with some type of illness and that they were still sick even when the Governor attacked them. How were they healed?  I remember Hershel was helping them out before he got beheaded. Was that what finally helped them to overcome the illness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During [Season 4 Episode 3- Isolation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948632/) Daryl, Tyreese, Michonne and Bob leave the prison to find some antibiotics at a veterinary college that Hershel knew about, they find the antibiotics in [Episode 4- Indifference](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948628/) and return to the prison in [Episode 5- Internment](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948636/) at which point Hershel and Bob begin to distribute it among the infected.

After they left in *Isolation*, Hershel had also left the prison with Carl to find some Elderberries which he made into tea, a natural remedy for the flu as they knew it would take a while for them to get to the clinic due to the large distance and walkers.